# flash cs4 , dynamic text field

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

Usually i am pretty good at working my way round as3 but this one is really giving me a headache

I have this code below and everything works fine i can trace the output but still the text is not showing up on stage any clues??

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var total:XMLList;
var totalPram:XMLList;
var totalImgs:XMLList;
var totalX:XMLList;
var totalY:XMLList;
var totalInfo:XMLList;
var pram:XML;
var img:XML;
var playHead:Number=0;
var spacer:Number=20;
var xpos:Number=300;
var ypos:Number=100;
/////////////////////////////// formating ///////////////////////////////////
var newFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();// Text formating
newFormat.size=30;
newFormat.bold;
newFormat.font="Arial";
newFormat.color="0xCBFF00";
//newFormat.leading=-7;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("info_1.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
//var tagHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
xmlData=new XML(e.target.data);
xmlData.ignoreWhite=true;
Parseinfo(xmlData);

}
function Parseinfo(Details:XML):void {
total=Details.blink;
totalPram=Details.blink.tag;
totalInfo=Details.blink.more;
totalImgs=Details.blink.img;
totalY=Details.totalY.ypos;
totalX=Details.totalX.xpos;
for (var i=0; i<=1; i++) {
    //addChild(tagHolder);
    pram=totalPram[i];
    var labels:TextField=new TextField  ;// txtfield for questions to be    displayed
    labels.setTextFormat(newFormat);
    //mytxt2.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    labels.embedFonts=true;
    labels.text=pram;
    labels.x=xpos+spacer;
    labels.y=ypos;
    trace(labels.text);
    addChild(labels);

}
```

}

Comment: This might just be my preference, but it's suggested that function names and variables name begin with lowercase letters. This consistency will help in the future when you or someone else is debugging your code.

Comment: click on the green checkmark near Sandro's answer so that this question appears answered in the listings (and sandro gets the reputation points that he deserve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
labels.defaultTextFormat=newFormat;
```

instead of

```
labels.setTextFormat(newFormat);
```

this will solve the problem of embed fonts as well. Thank you everyone for the help though

Comment: I started to have the same problem with embedded fonts right after i cleaned up my library. defaultTextFormat doesn't help though.

Answer (score 1):

You are placing the textfields on top of each other.

```
var spacer:Number=20;
var xpos:Number=300;
var ypos:Number=100;

labels.x=xpos+spacer; //always 320
labels.y=ypos;        //always 100
```

Comment: i still should be able to see text on top of each other  right?

Comment: how about setting `labels.text = "some hard coded value";` - does it work?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see is on the line where you create the TextField it should be:

```
var labels:TextField=new TextField();
```

Also, try doing this without using setTextFormat() to check if the problem is the embedded font or something else.

Comment: Though it doesn't look nice, it's okay to call constructors like that if there's no parameter involved

Comment: I did and nothing changed so far

Comment: Is your trace working? Try tracing the XML side-by-side to the TextField.text

Comment: trace is working fine and i can see the results there but no display

Comment: got it!!.. it was embed font i just commented that out

Comment: Good! Embedding a font is pretty easy, but you gotta follow all the steps. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you embed the font and that it is tracing out what the textfield is saying.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
According to the as3 TextField documentation:

> If you set the embedFonts property to
>   true for a text field, you must
>   specify a font for that text by using
>   the font property of a TextFormat
>   object applied to the text field. **If
>   the specified font is not embedded in
>   the SWF file, the text is not
>   displayed.**

In other words you need to have some dynamic text field with embedded font on the stage when you add one programatically or, alternatively, you can create your own font symbol with Export option to the library and add it to your TextField:

```
var myFont:Font = new MyFont();
...
newFormat.font = myFont.fontName;
```

I guess you already figured it out by now. I hope it will be helpful for someone else =)

**EDIT:**

In this case you should use

```
labels.setTextFormat(newFormat);
```

Instead of

```
labels.defaultTextFormat = newFormat;
```

The last one doesn't seem to work for me.